# Tests for polymorphic nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to fix the default tests for a polymorphic nested resource and running into lots of issues. I'm betting there is a simple solution that this newbie just hasn't wrapped his head around yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated as always.

My Models:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :names, as: :person
  has_many :dependents

 attr_accessible :active, :deleted
 end

 class Name < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :person, polymorphic: true

    attr_accessible :dob, :dod, :first, :gender, :last, :mi, :prefix, :relation, :suffix
 end
```

routes.rb:

```
  resources :dependents do
    resources :names 
  end

  resources :members do
   resources :names 
  end
```

Example Test:

```
 require 'test_helper'

class NamesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
 setup do
  @name = names(:one)
  @person = members(:one)
 end

test "should get edit" do
  get :edit, id: @name
   assert_response :success
 end
 end
```

Error I'm receiving:

> 3) Error:
>   test_should_get_edit(NamesControllerTest):
>   ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:id=>"980190962", :person_id=>"980190962", :controller=>"names", :action=>"edit"}
>       /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:544:in `raise_routing_error'
>       /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:540:in`rescue in generate'
>       /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:532:in `generate'
>       /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:573:in`generate'
>       /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:569:in `generate_extras'
>       /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:565:in`extra_keys'
>       /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:153:in `assign_parameters'
>       /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:465:in`process'
>       /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:49:in `process'
>       /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:392:in`get'
>       /Users/mkenney/hraccess/test/functional/names_controller_test.rb:43:in `block in '

If I add back in the non-nested route to names these errors run. How do I tell the test that it is a nested resource and does this have anything to do with the polymorphic relationship, or is that just noise that is throwing me off?

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer this newbie!

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add the member_id to get the proper route I believe:

```
test "should get edit" do
  get :edit, member_id: @person, id: @name
  assert_response :success
end
```